# Tensorflow=2.11 version not found when installing

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I have python 3.10.6 installed.
i am following the [TFOD course](https://github.com/nicknochnack/TFODCourse)
i installed TensorFlow 2.11
while training the mode the gpu was not being used and therefore the process was very slow.
then i installed CUDA 11.2 and Cudnn 8.1
but when i installed tensorflow-gpu 2.11.0 it says

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==2.11 (from versions: 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==2.11

alter

I tried uninstalling TensorFlow 2.11 and installing 2.10,
and installed tensorflow2.10.0.
Did not update cuda and cudnn as same versions were required
I was hoping that it would run on GPU this time. but it did not

Comment: What error does it show after your final step of uninstalling TF 2.11 and reintsalling TF 2.10? Please follow the step by step instructions mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) for the GPU setup in your system along with checking the Hardware/ Software requirements. GPU support is available only till TF 2.10.

Answer (score 0):

> TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on
> native-Windows. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you will need to
> install TensorFlow in WSL2, or install tensorflow or tensorflow-cpu
> and, optionally, try the TensorFlow-DirectML-Plugin

Please follow the step by step instructions mentioned in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) and try again by creating a new Virtual environment and install TensorFlow 2.10 and supporting [software](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#software_requirements) to have GPU support enabled in your system.